# How to know whether a css animation ended in its last keyframe(100%), and not (0%). React & CSS

Tags: css, reactjs

So i have an eventListener for `onAnimationEnd` and make it run code on my element that has some animations. Details of the animation properties on the element:

```
  animation: border-fade-out-part1 linear forwards;
  animation-timeline: view();
  animation-range-start: 750px;
  animation-range-end: 1350px;
```

When `onAnimationEnd` is ran, it works properly without any issues, but i noticed that it runs whenever the animation 'literally' ends, as in like the code from the eventListener is ran regardless of the starting keyframe(either 0% and 100%) and the last keyframe(either 0% and 100%).
This occurs since my animation is dependent on the `animation-timeline: view()` I believe, since that the animation plays whenever the element is on `view()`.

I tried getting hold of the event and checking its certain properties I have checked in the internet like `e.elapsedTime` and `e.animationDuration`. To hopefully get hold of which keyframe it started and ended at.

```
  function handleAnimationEnd(e) {
    console.log(e.animationName, e.elapsedTime, e.animationDuration)
  }
```

But after running the code, its log:
`border-fade-out-part1 0.0192 undefined`
which didn't help at all.